# Javascript What are the arguments for object.call?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor

NOT I DON'T KNOW HOW OTHERS WORDED THIS QUESTION IF THIS IS A DUPLICATE

So i have been starting to leard oop in js. It is my first language. Out of the 3 elements, i have decided to start learning inheritance. I seem to have grasp objects inheriting from other objects, though i have not applied it to any coding challenges yet.

But the problem: I tried learning constructors inheriting from constructors, and i learned you need object.call().

According to Mozila.developer, the this is a provided argument. I am assuming that i do not have to worry about it.

But I am confused on what the arguments do after the this.

From mozilla:

"Parameters

thisArg
The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.
arg1, arg2, ...
Arguments for the object.
Return value

The result of calling the function with the specified this value and arguments."

Example:

```
function a(r){
    this.r = r;
}

function b(r){
    a.call(this, .....)
}

b.prototype = object.create(a.prototype);
```

Comment: I guess you're referring to the *call* method of Function objects, i.e. the one inherited from [*Function.prototype.call*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.call) on MDN [*here*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)?

Comment: yes this is the correct one right? for inheriting  constructors with constructors?

Comment: It seems you first have to learn how `this` works. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes .

Comment: *"Out of the 3 elements, i have decided to start learning inheritance"* - What are the other two? (I suspect you've picked the most confusing thing to start with.)

Comment: the other 2 are polymorphism ad encapsulation. After inheritance, which should i learn next?

Comment: Also, i believe i do unterstand the the "this" keyword. Pls correct me if i am wrong. I will then look that the link you give me:This is a place holder, so then any other object can use that property or method

Answer (score 1):

> But I am confused on what the arguments do after the this.

The arguments after the `thisArg` are passed one-by-one to the called function. In your example:

```
function A(r_a){
    this.r = r_a;
}

function B(r_b){
    A.call(this, r_b)
}

var b = new B(1)
```

The value `1` is passed to `B` where it is available as `r_b`, which is passed via the `call` method into `A` where it is available as the `r_a` parameter and ends up in the `b.r` property.

You can pass arbitrarily many arguments this way.

Answer (score 0):

`.call()` invokes the function that you call it on. The first parameter passed to it becomes `this` inside that function. the rest are passed as the functions parameters. Simple example:

```
function callMe(param1, param2) {
  console.log(param1 + this.separator + param2);
}

callMe.call({ separator: ' ' }, 'Hello', 'world!'
```

So the object `{ separator: ' ' }` is set to `this`, 'Hello' and 'world!' are passed to `callMe` as `param1` and `param2`

results in:

> "Hello World!"

---

So in your example, you probably want to do:

```
function b(r){
  a.call(this, r)
}
```

which would just invoke the `a()` function and forward the parameter `r` to it.

---

The reason you can't just do:

```
function b(r) {
  a(r);
}
```

is that the `this` context inside `a()` would be wrong. Using `.call()` here preserves the `this` context when invoking `a()`, so `b()` and `a()` both execute with the same `this` context.